# Using java generic types for type transformation

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have an `Object o` that can be casted to type A and type B. 
I need a function `transformForType(Type t, Object o)` that takes a type, lets say A or B and checks if o its that type and process it to transform it. 
The usage of the function would be something like that: `B result = tranformForType(B.class, o);`

My question is whats the way to define the `tranformForType` function, and if its posible whats the best way using generic types.

Regards.

Comment: It's best not to forget what type `o` was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
static <T> T transformForType(Class<T>, Object o) { ...
```

that one has no restrictions whatsoever on that T type, but of course, if A/B implement the same interface, or have the same base class, you can further refine that T:

```
static <T extends ABInterface> T transformForType(Class<T>, Object o) { ...
```

for example.

And please note: obviously, when you don't have any restrictions on that type you wish to cast, you go with the other answer and call `SomeClass.class.cast()`. But if you want to allow only specific types, you might want to use such a `transformForType()` method (which would then use that very `cast()` method)!

Comment: but the problem is: how can i invoke this tranformForType(Class<T>, Object o) method?

Comment: @Cam it should match exactly how you invoke that method in your example within your question?!

Answer (score 4):

The `Class` class already has a method to cast an object at runtime -- [the `cast` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)):

> Casts an object to the class or interface represented by this `Class` object.

You just need to call it.  It'll throw a `ClassCastException` like a normal cast would.

```
B result = B.class.cast(o);
```

Comment: Definitely a good approach, and thanks for leaving a bit of room for another answer ;-)

Comment: @rgettman can you overwrite this cast method? and if its the case, where? in B as a static method?

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite this method?  It's built-in to Java.  In case you mean "override", you can't -- the `Class` class is `final`.

Comment: That's the problem, Objects can be A, B, C, etc.. and the code should be capable to transform an object A to B, or B to C.